# How do I fix the WiFi for my Arris router/modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I restarted my Arris router/modem and now it is not broadcasting the WiFi SSID. I have `Broadcast Network Name (SSID)` checked/enabled, WiFi is enabled also, and channel selection is set to automatic. I tried manually setting the channel to 11, then 6, but no luck. MAC Filtering Mode is set to Allow-All. I cannot see the SSID on my iPhone nor a Samsung laptop. I have restarted the router several times.

- Model:TG862G
- Hardware Revision: 5
- eMTA & DOCSIS Software Version: 9.1.103M2AM.SIP.PC20.CT
- Packet Cable:2.0

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart it via the Comcast account page https://customer.xfinity.com/#/devices. Then my devices were able to see it and connect to it. (This also fixed an (un?)related speed issue of only 0.5Mbps down, 1.5Mbps up.)

By the way, somehow Comcast knows my WiFi password even though it is a used router I bought from a friend and I entered it directly manually from the admin page on 10.0.0.1. That would mean Comcast knows everyone's WiFi passwords and anyone who hacks Comcast (or employees) can get into anyone's WiFi network.

[image]

Comment: BTW, there's a standard protocol called "TR-069" that many ISPs use to manage the modems/gateways they give/lease/sell to customers. If that device originally came from Comcast (i.e. if the previous owner had purchased it from Comcast) then it may have been preconfigured so that Comcast could manage it via TR-069. So, while still creepy, this may not be as creepy as it first appears. Does the admin UI give you a way to disable TR-069?

Comment: Followup to my previous comment: if the device has "xfinity" printed on the front, then it is technically a TG862G/CT, which is a Comcast-specific version of the TG862G, increasing the likelihood that it was preconfigured to be remotely manageable by Comcast Xfinity.